# How to Read from Excel files in mapreduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have an Excel File which has many sheets (around 50) in HDFS. i have to read from one sheet of Excel File using mapreduce. Can anyone suggest how can i do that?

Comment: What you have done so far?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is suggested here - [Reading a excel file in hadoop map reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868631/reading-a-excel-file-in-hadoop-map-reduce)

otherwise someone has already created excel input format as an standard solution for this kind of problem. Read this -https://sreejithrpillai.wordpress.com/2014/11/06/excel-inputformat-for-hadoop-mapreduce/

A github project is there with codebase.

Look here - https://github.com/sreejithpillai/ExcelRecordReaderMapReduce/

Hope this should give you a start point.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is the HadoopOffice library, which allows you to read/write Excel documents in Hadoop/Spark.

https://github.com/ZuInnoTe/hadoopoffice/wiki